# Singleton Issue in C++

Tags: c++, singleton

Currently I am facing an issue related to Singleton classes. Here is the scenario : I have 3 Singleton Classes namely

```
class BaseConfiguration : public TSingleton<BaseConfiguration>{
};

class ComponentConfiguration : public BaseConfiguration, public TSingleton<ComponentConfiguration>{
};

class ComposedConfiguration : public BaseConfiguration, public TSingleton<ComposedConfiguration >{
};
```

ComponentConfiguration and ComposedConfiguration should initiailize BaseConfiguration because they both use BaseConfiguration. Also BaseConfiguration can be initiailize as its own.

```
ComposedConfiguration * InitializeComposed()
{
  TSingleton<BaseConfiguration>::CreateInstance();
  return TSingleton<ComposedConfiguration >::CreateInstance();
}

ComponentConfiguration* InitializeComponent()
{
  TSingleton<BaseConfiguration>::CreateInstance();
  return TSingleton<ComponentConfiguration>::CreateInstance();
}

BaseConfiguration * InitializeBaseConfig()
{
 return TSingleton<BaseConfiguration>::CreateInstance();
}
```

Composed and Component Configuration are independent.

Issue is how to destroy the instance of BaseConfiguration. It is possible that both Composed and component configuration are using the instance of Base Configuration and For example : On destroying Composed, if I destroy Base Configuration in destructor, component configuration will crash. Also It is also possible that BaseConfiguration is initialized using InitializeBaseConfig function. 
What is the best way to delete BaseConfiguration instance or calling TSingleton::DestroyInstance() so no module will crash and without leaking any memory.

Thanks

Comment: This seems fairly different from the C++ singleton pattern with which I am familiar.

Comment: Why not use Scott Meyer's Singleton ? static Singleton& instance(){ static Singleton s; return s; }

Comment: Any link where I can get information about Scott Meyer's Singleton

Comment: http://silviuardelean.ro/2012/06/05/few-singleton-approaches/

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to simply don't inherit from `BaseConfiguration`. These are Singletons, thus static variables and methods in disguise, so there is little benefit from inheritance. If you want to provide same methods from `BaseConfiguration` in the other singletons, write simple wrappers, like:

```
some_type SomeMethod() { 
    return TSingleton<BaseConfiguration>::Instance()->SomeMethod();
}
```

Unless there several dozens of them, it's not a problem.

My other suggestion would be to drop the Singleton pattern altogether. Have regular classes. Their objects can then have regular lifetimes. If you really don't need more than one, that's fine, just don't allocate more than one. In that case, you can inherit from some `BaseConfig` if you wish and there will not be anything special about it. You can also avoid inheritance and have both configuration objects keep a `std::shared_ptr<>` to a `BaseConfig` object, if you want to avoid having two `BaseConfig` sub-objects in the two configuration objects.